# How to run SQL Queries on EF?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, entity-framework

I am working on EF with C# and WPF as front end. I need to provide a UI for so user can create his own query and get the result. The UI will be list of tables and list of columns to select from (Not happy with UI. Need to improve but new ticks in my mind).

So my question is how create, merge(existing query) and execute the queries.

There are sql class Entity Client provider, objectquery class. I used ObjectQuery

```
string querystring = @"SELECT PrjDev FROM prjscenario"; 
ObjectQuery<PrjDev> prjdevquery = new ObjectQuery<PrjDev>(querystring, ptxobjcontext);
string cpmmandtext = prjdevquery.CommandText;
int prjdevnum =  prjdevquery.Count();
```

It is working. But when i run some complex query. It is not working. Example code :

```
string querystring = @"SELECT PrjDev FROM prjscenario WHERE PrjDev.PrjDevType = 10";
```

Error :

> 'PrjDevType' is not a member of
>   'Transient.collection[Skm.Ptx.Data.Emf.PrjDev(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=)]'.
>   To extract a property of a collection
>   element, use a subquery to iterate
>   over the collection. Near simple
>   identifier, line 1, column 45.

Any Idea, why it is good for one simple query but it is not working for complex queries?

Thanks in Advance,
N

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query passed as a parameter to the `ObjectQuery<T>` constructor is NOT an SQL query, it's an ESQL (Entity SQL) query. While similar in syntax, they are very different languages. You can learn more about ESQL [on this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx).

If you want to execute real SQL against the ObjectContext's underlying database, you can use the `ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery` method, or just retrieve the connection through the `ObjectContext.Connection` property and write "classic" ADO.NET code from there.

Comment: Hi Thomas,I was looking on ExecuteStoreQuery and E SQL. First ExecuteStoreQuery looks good to me. It perfectly works with simple query. But When i pass complex query with join over three tables. It breaks by error like The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Emf.PrjDevCable'. A member of the type, 'PrjDevID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Comment: It won't work for anonymous types, only for named types (because you can't specify the anonymous type as the generic type parameter). The query needs to return the same column names as in your model

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue an come here to answer i see your post. I did the same thing. I was using Select Name,Type From Table Joins..... Now I use Select * From Table Join.... On a Short note, L2S Support both. But EMF works well only with Select * ....Thanks,N

Comment: I heard in some blog that your could use ExecuteStoreQuery<DbDataRecord> to achieve a pseudo generic type, but I couldn't make it work in my current project. There is little to none documentation about how to use this implementation, wish you have some tip regarding this Thomas. Link : http://geekswithblogs.net/rgupta/archive/2010/06/23/entity-framework-v4-ndash-tips-and-tricks.aspx